# Plot in R a Chart Line

Tags: r, plot, linechart

I am new in R and Iam looking how to plot a simple  Line Chart.

```
cars <- c(27.91, 28.13, 28.23, 28.41, 28.58, 28.61, 28.78, 28.89)

plot(cars, type="o" , xlab="Taille de séquences",
    ylab="Nombre de séquences", names.arg=c("10","20","50","100","150", "200", "250"), 
    border="blue")
```

My problem is in the Y axis i cannot find these numbers : "10","20","50","100","150", "200", "250

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `warnings()` and you'll see that there are no `names.arg` for `plot` (unlike `barplot`). You can accomplish that with:

```
plot(cars, type="o" , xlab="Taille de séquences", ylab="Nombre de séquences", yaxt="n")
axis(2, cars, c("10","20","50","100","150", "200", "250", NA)) #You did not specify one argument, I used NA.
```

Comment: Thank you Mox for yyour help

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra If this answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it to remove this question from "need answers".